# How to make icon button stick to the left side of the navbar

Tags: reactjs

I have this component here that makes a navbar but as of right now the avatar button is right next to the "home" button. I'm fairly new to react and web programming so I'm not sure what to look for to make the avatar button stick to the right corner of the navbar.

The navbar right now:
[image]

The navbar I want to display:
[image]

```
export default function MenuAppBar() {
    const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(true);
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setAuth(event.target.checked);
    };

    const handleMenu = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    return (
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        size="large"
                        edge="start"
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="menu"
                        onClick={handleMenu}
                        sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                        <Menu
                            id="menu-appbar"
                            anchorEl={anchorEl}
                            anchorOrigin={{
                                vertical: 'top',
                                horizontal: 'right',
                            }}
                            keepMounted
                            transformOrigin={{
                                vertical: 'top',
                                horizontal: 'right',
                            }}
                            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                            onClose={handleClose}
                        >
                            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
                    </IconButton>
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/home" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                    Bookeroo
                    </a>
                    {auth && (
                        <div>
                            <IconButton
                                size="large"
                                aria-label="account of current user"
                                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                onClick={handleMenu}
                                color="inherit"
                            >
                                <AccountCircle />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Menu
                                id="menu-appbar"
                                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                                anchorOrigin={{
                                    vertical: 'top',
                                    horizontal: 'right',
                                }}
                                keepMounted
                                transformOrigin={{
                                    vertical: 'top',
                                    horizontal: 'right',
                                }}
                                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                                onClose={handleClose}
                            >
                                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                            </Menu>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Comment: This is a `css` (styling) problem and not a `react` problem. Are you using any UI framework?

Comment: @codebarz no I'm not

Answer (score 1):

So, I am going to assume your mark up is something like (not necessarily exact)

```
<div className="wrapper">
   <div className="toggle">toggle</div>
   <div className="item">Home</div>
   <div className="icon">icon</div>
</div>
```

I would make the `wrapper` a flex box and make the `icon` move to the right. Like this

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

The `margin: auto` forces the item to the end depending on the direction of the margin (margin-left to right end, margin-right to left end, and so on)